# Sync with Server every 30 minutes in android?

Tags: android, android-background

I want the android app to sync with the server every 30 (or any interval) minutes and notify user if there is any change.

I have already tried `[JobScheduler][1]`. It seems like `[JobScheduler][1]` runs the event at optimized interval not at exact interval.   Some one suggested `[AlarmManager][1]` but i don't think that will also work - It also checks the battery optimization.   (`setExactTime` and `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` also runs at optimized time)

I want the app to sync with the server at exact interval no matter what.

Comment: try using timer , start the timer on onCreate()  and onDestroy() remove  on destroy .

Comment: Why? "I want the app to sync with the server at exact interval no matter what."

Comment: It is monitoring app.  It needs to notify user immediately

Comment: create a **background** `service` in which you can set a **timer** at that time send a call to the server and get new data if any change happens then notify the user through `NotificationDailog`.

Comment: Use `JobScheduler`

Comment: use Android-Job from evernote

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer for this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Then you extend the timer task

```
class SyncData extends TimerTask {


   public void run() {
       //call after every 30min
   }
}
```

And then add the new task to the Timer with some update interval

```
TimerTask syncData = new SyncData();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(syncData,1000*10);//this will run after every 10 sec
```

Note: It will only work if your application is not in background if you want to call api when your application is in background than please user **Service** and **AlaramManager**.